# How to invoke methods inside a service using wso2 proxy service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to wso2

I have created two jar services

**1) Simple service has two methods add and subtract two numbers**

**2) simple service has two methods multiply and divide two numbers**

I want to invoke these two services based on some condition,that i have implemented using Filter Mediator.

I want to call the methods inside those services.

Say, If `a > b` I called first service,then I want to call the operations(methods) inside these service,say `addTwoNumbers(int a,int b)` and `subTwoNumberes(int a , int b)`

How to call these methods using proxy service?

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Thanks Prime.. Can you help me for the solution ...

Comment: If I understand, your services aren't deploy as Webservices, you just want to call those classes methods from java ?

Comment: No Jean.. I have deployed those services as JAR services.. I have two operations in those services.. So how i need to call those methods using a proxy service,,

Answer (score 0):

You have two backend services and you want expose both service as one proxy service.. then this proxy service must capable of deciding the backend service that message must be sent.  So,  you can create one proxy service using WSO2ESB and you can attach a new WSDL for it.  Once message is received to proxy service,  filer mediator can use to send it to different BE based on the parameters. You can extract the `a` and `b` values from the incoming message by using XPath expression. Then these two values can be compared. Once filter mediator compares them, you can build the SOAP message that is required to send to your services.

You can use following WSO2ESB docs for this..

1.[How to create proxy service](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Adding+a+Proxy+Service)
2.[XPath](http://rajikak.blogspot.com/2010/04/xpath-functions-and-properties-avilable.html)
3.[Filter mediator](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Filter+Mediator)
4.[PayloadFactory Mediator](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/PayloadFactory+Mediator)

Also please refer ESB docs,  you may fine more details

Comment: Thanks Asela for the response.. Actually how can i pass that two values a and b to proxy service? and how i can call that method AddTwoNUmbers inside the backend service? I didn't get a clear idea since i am new to wso2

Comment: You can use `PayloadFactory Mediator` to create the play load for your `AddTwoNUmbers` service.. the service parameters can be (it means `a` `b` values can be copied from incoming message). Then you  only need to define an endpoint address of the `AddTwoNUmbers` service

Comment: I guess, it is better to go through them,  you can get some idea  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmNf-2VljLQ   https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Service+Chaining+Example